# For loop not properly appending values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Im trying to store 60 values to x and the next one to the y and then shift it 1 up and store 60 values to x and the next one to the y. But the for loop only works once for the x values the y values some how do get stored properly. And the size of my dataset is not the problem as storing the y values work. It's just the x values that don't store and when debugging the x sets are just empty array's except the first one. What am i doing wrong?

```
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')

print(df)

dataset = df.values

data_len = math.ceil(len(dataset) * .1)

data = dataset[0:data_len , :]
print(data)

x = []
y = []

for i in range(60, len(data)):
    x.append(data[60-i:i, 0])
    y.append(data[i, 0])
```

Comment: I suspect the line before the last one should be: `x.append(data[i-60:i, 0])`

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski What do you exactly mean?

Comment: Maybe you should show a simple example of data and expected result for "x" (but with e. g. only 10 values or so) as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: I think you put `60-i` instead of `i-60`

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski that fixed it thanks.

Comment: Do you mean 60 values in `x`, the 61st in `y`, 62-121 in `x`, 122nd in `y` and so on and so forth?

Comment: Please provide sample data in a [reproducible way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391). Otherwise people won't be able to test. Please also show the expected output explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should try to avoid using a for loop, in numpy it is often faster to create masks and work with that.  If i understand your question correctly, you want to store 0-59 in x, then 60 in y, then 61-119 in x, then 120 in y and so on.

If that is the correct understanding i would try this instead:

```
dataset = np.random.randint(1,1000,size=1000) #generating an example

mask = np.zeros(len(dataset),dtype=np.bool)
mask[60::60] = 1 #indices of the ys

y = dataset[mask]
x = dataset[~mask]
```